# What does the error message "Universe inconsistency" mean when working with higher-rank types?

Tags: idris, higher-rank-types

Given the following Idris code:

```
import Data.Vect
import Data.Fin

%default total

fins : Vect n (Fin n)
fins {n = Z} = []
fins {n = S n} = FZ :: map FS fins

Permutation : Nat -> Type
Permutation n = {a : Type} -> Vect n a -> Vect n a

permutations : {n : Nat} -> Vect (fact n) (Permutation n)
permutations {n = Z} = [id]
permutations {n = S n} =
    rewrite multCommutative (S n) (fact n) in
    concat $ map inserts (permutations {n = n})
  where
    inserts : Permutation k -> Vect (S k) (Permutation (S k))
    inserts pi = map (\i => \(x :: xs) => insertAt i x . pi $ xs) fins
```

I am getting the following error message from Idris 0.9.16 (and no further details):

```
Type checking .\Permutations.idr
Permutations.idr:15:14:Universe inconsistency
```

However, by changing it just so slightly, so that the second clause of `permutations` becomes

```
permutations {n = S n} =
    rewrite multCommutative (S n) (fact n) in
    concat . map inserts $ permutations {n = n}
```

then it suddenly typechecks.

Is there some special magic going on inside Idris perhaps in the handling of `($)` and `(.)`, [similar to what GHC does](http://www.mail-archive.com/glasgow-haskell-users@haskell.org/msg18923.html) so that they work in the presence of higher-rank types?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of Idris 0.10.2, my original code (using `concat $ map inserts (permutations {n = n})` in the definition of `permutations`) typechecks without hiccup.

Comment: So, pretend I don't know anything about idris; what's the actual answer here - "it was a bug"?

Comment: I imagine so... the two definitions should be equivalent.